# Kotlinx.Serialization: Exclude object from serialization if all inner properties are also excluded

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I’m trying to implement functionality that excludes the whole object from the serialization if all inner objects are excluded.

For example when I want to serialize this data class to json

```
data class Car(val engine: Engine? = null, val size: Size?  = null)
data class Engine(val type: String?  = null, val horsePower: Int?  = null)
data class Size(val size: Int? = null)

Car(engine = Engine(horsePower = null), size = Size(size = 1000))
```

then I should get the following output (engine is excluded even if it is set)

```
car {
    size {
        size = 1000
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any tip on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

For `kotlinx.serialization` use `@kotlinx.serialization.Transient`

```
data class Car(
   
   @kotlinx.serialization.Transient
   val engine: Engine? = null
   ...
```